# Count rows grouped by time intervals?

Tags: mysql, time, intervals

Currently I have an access log for my tools created on my server. The tools do not expire, however they are all created at different times (much like products). They have id's, various data fields and also a timestamp when they were created.

What I need, is to group and count the access log entries into x intervals depending on time. Right now I'm tinkering with 10 steps (intervals). I want to count the access entries during those 10 intervals, thus having a sort of reference of usage depending on time. I'm not using a *fixed* time interval, my interval is (Current Time - Added Time) / 10.

This is my output goal:

```
From: 1351159089
Now: 1353932533

From           To               Entries
1351159089   - 1351436433.4  =  2
1351436433.4 - 1351713777.8  =  1
1351713777.8 - 1351991122.2  =  0
1351991122.2 - 1352268466.6  =  2
1352268466.6 - 1352545811    =  5
1352545811   - 1352823155.4  =  0
1352823155.4 - 1353100499.8  =  2
1353100499.8 - 1353377844.2  =  0
1353377844.2 - 1353655188.6  =  2
1353655188.6 - 1353932533    =  3
```

What I do now is just using PHP and multiple queries:

```
$from = strtotime($timeCreated);
$now = time();
$dif = $now-$from;

$steps = $dif/10;

for($i=0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $intervalFrom = $from+($steps*$i);
    $intervalTo = $intervalFrom+$steps;
    $get = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT count(id) as `total` FROM `access_log` WHERE `time` >= FROM_UNIXTIME('.$intervalFrom.') AND `time` < FROM_UNIXTIME('.$intervalTo.') AND `item` = "'.$itemID.'"'));
    $accessLogs[$i] = $get['total'];
}
```

I wouldn't say it's slow, but on one page I may have 5-10 or more of these, and then it begins to show the drawbacks of having bunches of queries going for just one item.

Is there a smarter and **faster** way to get this output using just one or two MySQL queries?

Thanks

Edit: It's been so long, wonder if this could be done?

Comment: A time value of when the entry was created. As in the output the beginning is 1351159089 ($timeCreated after converted to a unix timestamp) and the end is 1353932533 (time();)

Comment: strange that theres no answer to this, or even a link to already solved Q!